# Bootstrap daterangepicker not work in mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, webview

I am using this template (https://colorlib.com/polygon/gentelella/index.html) in my website, the date picker in the page works fine in my computer, but it does not work properly in mobile (Safari or other webkit browsers), any dates in the the first calendar cannot be selected, [image: Dates in the red frame can not be selected]

but the dates in the second calendar work properly.

Answer (score 0):

I upgraded bootstrap-daterangepicker to the latest version, the issue disappeared.